# Fitting textViews in LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have four textViews which are on the the same linear layout.When I'm running my application on my phone it looks ok,but when I run it on a tablet they are as if they were displayed on my phone.Meaning the don't expand and use the empty space provided.Can you tell me how i can achieve this?Hope I was clear.

Comment: paste your xml layout out code to give answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying using `android:layout_weight` when defining your TextViews. An example would be `android:layout_weight=".25"` for each of your TextViews so they take up equal amount of space within the LinearLayout.
You might want to use `android:gravity="center"` in your LinearLayout as well so the children display from the center.

Hope this is what you are after.